# Oracle Outer join with 0 value return for non existing rows

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

I have 2 tables

```
Person
--------------------
id   name   dept_id
---------------------
1   x        1
2   y        1
3   z        2

Feedback
------------------------------------
person_id  f_date  positive  negative 
------------------------------------
1    2014-05-05    10     4
1    2014-05-15    5      3
2    2014-05-11    3      8
```

Now my query is

```
SELECT p.id, 
       nvl(sum(positive),0) AS pf,
       nvl(sum(negative),0) AS nf 
  FROM person p 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN feedback f ON p.id = f.person_id
 WHERE f_date BETWEEN to_date('2014-05-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                  AND to_date('2014-05-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
 GROUP BY p.id
 ORDER BY p.id;
```

I expect to see

```
id   pf    nf
---------------
1   15     7
2   3      8
3   0      0
```

but I don't see the the data for 3. In fact the data i get is only if the rows exist in feedback table as if its an equi join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause is turning the outer join into an inner join.  The solution is to move the condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT p.id, nvl(sum(positive),0) as pf, nvl(sum(negative),0) as nf 
FROM person p left outer JOIN
     feedback f
     on p.id = f.person_id and
        f.f_date between to_date('2014-05-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND to_date('2014-05-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.id;
```